# Is there a name for the series: line, rectangle, cuboid etc.?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Yeah, the question is pretty self-explanatory.

> Is there a name for the series: line, rectangle, cuboid etc.?

I need a general name for the series of these geometric shapes for my proof of a generalization of a problem I'm working on. The context is not important here. Also, if a name doesn't exist, how would I define this series?

Comment: We call the set {Line, Square, Cube, Tesseract,...} as set of hypercubes.

Comment: The four dimensional cube is called "tesseract" coming from Greek word "tessera" for the number 4. Maybe you like to modify the rest five-, six-,... dimensional cubes as well.

Comment: [*Orthotope*, or *hyperrectangle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperrectangle).

Comment: @Rahul: It's somehow strange that the figure from two-dimensional Euclidean space is used as the base here, while usually the three-dimensional space figure name is used (hypercube, not hypersquare; hyperplane, not hyperline; hypersphere, not hypercircle).

Comment: @celtschk: I agree. I guess the word *cuboid* is not as well known. I also like the term *box*, as in box constraints in numerical optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way often is to take the three-dimensional word and give the dimension separately.
That is, I would call the $n$th element on your list the $n$-dimensional cuboid.
This is similar (in language) to the $n$-dimensional balls.